# Need to run multiple md5 operations after ssh into a server

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I currently need to run multiple md5 operations(> 15000) on files after ssh'ing into the server. But my current implementation is extremely slow because a new channel using exec_command is created for every md5 operation. Is there a better way to do it using paramiko ?

```
def md5(fname):
    hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
    if os.path.isfile(fname):
        with open(fname, "rb") as f:
            for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
                hash_md5.update(chunk)
    return hash_md5.hexdigest()

def connect_server(host1):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(host1)
    return ssh

for files in install_files:
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('md5 %s' % files)
    file_md5_map[file] = stdout.read().split()[0]
```

Comment: How do you calculate md5? Using that custom md5 function? Why don't use command `md5sum`? It is faster, but calculating md5 is still a costly operation.

Comment: Yes, but what I noticed is the actual md5 operation is not expensive, but the ssh.exec_command is proving to be time consuming.

Comment: It may be caused by network lag. If you can use `md5sum`, you can calculate multiple files all at once by `md5sum file1 file2 file3...`. In this case, you only need to send one command to remote server.

Comment: If it *is* a latency issue -- there's no need to do only one `exec_command()` at a time. You can have multiple channels opened over the same transport, rather than waiting for one to finish before starting the next. You won't want to run all 15k at once, of course, but keeping a pool of them is a very good idea.

Comment: That said -- you've got some serious security issues the way you're doing this right now. If you have a file named `/tmp/$(rm -rf ~)` (and yes, it's a perfectly legal filename), then `'md5 %s' % file` will have *very* undesirable side effects. Always (always!) use `pipes.quote()` (in Python 2) or `shlex.quote()` (in Python 3) to escape content before substituting it into a command line.

Comment: (Lower-overhead, and better practice, would be to send a NUL-delimited stream of filenames to the remote process's stdin, and a NUL-delimited stream of hashes and filenames from its stdout).

Comment: Use `certutil` on Windows.  Example: `certutil -hashfile %userprofile%\myfile sha1`

Answer (score 0):

A high-performance implementation that calls `exec_command` only once (no matter how many files you have!) might look like the following:

```
remote_script = '''
exec 2>/dev/null ## writes to stderr will block; suppress them.
bash -s <<'EOF'
  while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
    result=$(md5 "$filename");
    result=${result%%[[:space:]]*}
    printf '%s\t%s\0' "${result}" "${filename}"
  done
EOF
'''
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(remote_script)

writer_thread = threading.Thread(
  target = lambda: stdin.write('\0'.join(install_files) + '\0')
)
writer_thread.start()

for datum in stdout.read().split('\0'):
    if len(datum) == 0: continue # should only happen for the last line
    (md5sum, filename) = datum.split('\t', 1)
    file_md5_map[filename] = md5sum
```

This passes the stream of filenames on the remote process's stdin:

```
/path/to/file1<NUL>/path/to/file2</NUL>
```

...and returns a stream of paired md5sums and filenames on its stdout:

```
md5_of_file1<TAB>/path/to/file1<NUL>md5_of_file2<TAB>/path/to/file2<NUL>
```

This means you only need to have a single remote process to convert this stream of input to output, and is completely robust against files with surprising or malicious names: Since the NUL character cannot possibly exist in a filename (unlike the newline character, which is often used as a delimiter *but shouldn't be*), using NULs to separate filenames is perfectly safe.